# How to list all the posts in /folder1/folder2/_post/ in jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I have a folder like this:

```
tutorials/
├── machine_learning
│   └── scikit_learn
│       ├── index.html
│       └── _post
│           └── 2014-09-22-my-title.md
└── web_design
    ├── index.html
    └── _post
        └── 2010-02-11-my-title.md
```

I want jekyll to list all the posts in /tutorials/machine_learning/scikit_learn/_post. How to do this?

I tried site.categories.tutorials.machine_learning.scikit_learn. It is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of categories in Jekyll.

Any post will have folder hierarchy names added in categories array.

We have two posts :

- **folder1** > _posts > YYYY-MM-DD-**one**.md
- **folder1** > **folder2** > _posts > YYYY-MM-DD-**two**.md

Post **one** will be in **folder1** category.

Post **two** will be in **folder1** and **folder** 2 categories.

Knowing our folder hierarchy, we just can pick at the right level

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.categories["folder1"] %}
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

- with site.categories["**folder1**"] we get posts **One** and **Two**
- with site.categories["**folder2**"] we get post **Two**

This was the easy use case.

Now, let's imagine that we have a hierarchy like :

```
.
├── steel
│   ├── brands
│   │   └── _posts
│   │       └── 2014-01-27-steel-brands.md
│   └── objects
│       └── _posts
│           └── 2014-01-27-steel-objects.md
└── wood
    ├── brands
    │   └── _posts
    │       └── 2014-01-27-wood-brands.md
    └── objects
        └── _posts
            └── 2014-01-27-wood-objects.md
```

If we want **wood objects**, we cannot simply loop in *site.categories["**objects**"]* because we'll also get posts from **steel objects**.

In order to get only wood objects we can do :

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.categories["objects"] %}
    {% if post.categories contains "wood" %}
      <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Note** : Always work with **post.categories**. Never with the **post.category**, it's buggy.